# Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I created an app on appstoreconnect and added an auto-renewable inApp purchase. It's status is Ready to submit.

But when I use the below code -

```
let productIDs = Set(["product_identifier"])

        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIDs)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
```

It always falls in

```
 func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {

    }
```

And the error is -

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://192.168.1.1/sgerror.php?url=403%20&a=192.168.1.102&n=192.168.1.102&i=&s=default&t=blk_BL_music&u=http://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZInit.woa/wa/initiateSession?ix=6&os=12&locale=en_IN, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://192.168.1.1/sgerror.php?url=403%20&a=192.168.1.102&n=192.168.1.102&i=&s=default&t=blk_BL_music&u=http://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZInit.woa/wa/initiateSession?ix=6&os=12&locale=en_IN, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <96039754-C60C-49C6-BC2F-07E237E8E691>.<258>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <96039754-C60C-49C6-BC2F-07E237E8E691>.<258>, NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}
```

Note : My Paid Apps Agreement is Active

Answer (score 0):

Something was wrong with my WiFi, Everything worked on Mobile Network.